# How to restart test on verify element present

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide, browser-automation

Am new with automation, and currently trying to do something in Selenium IDE but can't seem to find the information on how to do it properly.

So I am running a test on a webpage, clicks and such, and I want if a certain id element is on the page to restart the test, and if not to finish remaining of the code.

Alternatively, this can also be done by verify element not present, but I believe it will slow down the test by searching for something that isn't on the page most of the time.

So the intended steps:

1. Run Test;
2. Commands 1, 2, 3... are running
3. Before Command 19, element id=btnSalir is checked if present on the page
4. If true, test restarts and goes on the loop until id=btnSalir is not present on the page
5. If false, test runs remaining code or specific code, whichever is easier.

As alternative steps:

1. Run Test;
2. Commands 1, 2, 3... are running
3. Before Command 19, element id=btnSiguiente is checked if present on the page
4. If false, test restarts and goes on the loop until id=btnSiguiente is present on the page
5. If true, test runs remaining code or specific code, whichever is easier.

Also is there a way to reduce the amount of time on these verify element present or not present be reduced?

I tried if, do, repeat if, but can't make it work, maybe someone with some experience can give me some pointers?

[Selenium IDE step screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03ySi.png)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help:

if|selenium.isElementPresent("id=btnSalir")
echo|Do some thing
else
echo|Do some other thing
end

The code snippet in the IF statement uses an internal Selenium function to detect if the element is present.  The true or false result will cause the correct branch of the if-else-end statement to be executed.  Using a construct like this in a test in the IDE will let you do one thing if an element is present and a different thing if it is not present.
Note: This works if you run the test in the Selenium IDE, but will not work if you run the same test in the selenium Side Runner (the "selenium" object is not defined in the Side Runner).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).