# How to branch test steps with Selenium IDE based on Verify Element Present?

Tags: if-statement, selenium-ide

I'm using **Selenium IDE** (*browser add-on edition*) and I need to do proceed my testing based on the result of `verify element present` (or `verify element not present`)

currently, my test case looks like this:

```python
verify element present | id=helloworld
if                     | (previous command is TRUE)
  //do something
else
  //do something else
end
```

I don't know how to the value from '**verify element**' command so I cannot properly test it on my `if` statement.  Please note, that `id=helloworld` may or may not exist depends on external factor.

I tried below thinking it will store TRUE/FALSE on `commentResult` -- apparently, not.

```python
verify element present | id=helloworld         | commentResult
if                     | commentResult == true
  //do something
else
  //do something else
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In this use case, there's no need for `verify element present`.

Thanks to [user17273222](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69459680/how-to-restart-test-on-verify-element-present), simply check if element exists via `selenium.isElementPresent("element")`

Below is how the test case should look like:

```
if | selenium.isElementPresent("id=.zero_results")
  //do something
else
  //do something else
end
```